# jerssey anotation to filter request based on header value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

Is there any annotation available in jersey API to achieve request filtration based on header 
value? The same is achieved in spring like

**@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"version=v1.1"})**

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this by using annotations. However, you can access the HttpServletRequest, for example

```
public Response foo( @Context HttpServletRequest request ) {
    if( request.getHeader( "version" ).equals( "v1.1" ) }
       // ...
    }
}
```